# When I try to export Outlook 2010 tasks, Outlook crashes

Tags: microsoft-outlook, export, tasks, csv

When I try to export tasks from the Tasks folder of Outlook 2010 to either a tab-delimited or a comma-separated file, Outlook starts to export and then crashes with the options of trying to find a solution online and then restarting, or just restarting. Part of the desired file is created, but it is not complete.
Running Windows 7.
Things I have tried:
1. Exporting to both kinds of comma separated and both kinds of tab separated files
2. Running ScanPST.
3. Repairing Office from the Control Panel/Programs and Features
4. Exporting just one day's tasks
5. Starting in safe mode
6. Starting with what Microsoft calls a clean boot.